# Any Genetic Algorithms module for python 3.x?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I'm currently looking for a mature GA library for python 3.x. But the only GA library can be found are `pyevolve` and `pygene`. They both support python 2.x only. I'd appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

DEAP: Distributed Evolutionary Algorithms supports both Python 2 and 3:
http://code.google.com/p/deap

Disclaimer : I am one of the developers of DEAP.

Comment: Does DEAP support crossover and mutation if my chromosome is 2 dimensional array?

Comment: DEAP has problem with error: deap-1.2.2-py3.7.egg\deap\tools\_hypervolume\pyhv.py:33: ImportWarning: Falling back to the python version of hypervolume module. Expect this to be very slow. No advices work.

Comment: Hello, Do you have any detailed examples that explain the syntax used. I see an examples folder but the syntax (and flow) is not clear to me. Any details would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a benchmark page to compare it to single CPU/GPU implementations?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a GA library, but the book "Genetic Algorithms with Python" from Clinton Sheppard is quite useful as it helps you build your own GA library specified for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Check [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io), an open-source Python 3 library for implementing the genetic algorithm and training machine learning algorithms.

The documentation is available at Read the Docs: https://pygad.readthedocs.io

Install it via pip: `pip install pygad`

Here is an example that uses PyGAD to optimize a linear model.

```py
import pygad
import numpy

"""
Given the following function:
    y = f(w1:w6) = w1x1 + w2x2 + w3x3 + w4x4 + w5x5 + 6wx6
    where (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)=(4,-2,3.5,5,-11,-4.7) and y=44
What are the best values for the 6 weights (w1 to w6)? We are going to use the genetic algorithm to optimize this function.
"""

function_inputs = [4,-2,3.5,5,-11,-4.7] # Function inputs.
desired_output = 44 # Function output.

def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    # Calculating the fitness value of each solution in the current population.
    # The fitness function calulates the sum of products between each input and its corresponding weight.
    output = numpy.sum(solution*function_inputs)
    fitness = 1.0 / numpy.abs(output - desired_output)
    return fitness

fitness_function = fitness_func

num_generations = 100 # Number of generations.
num_parents_mating = 7 # Number of solutions to be selected as parents in the mating pool.

# To prepare the initial population, there are 2 ways:
# 1) Prepare it yourself and pass it to the initial_population parameter. This way is useful when the user wants to start the genetic algorithm with a custom initial population.
# 2) Assign valid integer values to the sol_per_pop and num_genes parameters. If the initial_population parameter exists, then the sol_per_pop and num_genes parameters are useless.
sol_per_pop = 50 # Number of solutions in the population.
num_genes = len(function_inputs)

init_range_low = -2
init_range_high = 5

parent_selection_type = "sss" # Type of parent selection.
keep_parents = 7 # Number of parents to keep in the next population. -1 means keep all parents and 0 means keep nothing.

crossover_type = "single_point" # Type of the crossover operator.

# Parameters of the mutation operation.
mutation_type = "random" # Type of the mutation operator.
mutation_percent_genes = 10 # Percentage of genes to mutate. This parameter has no action if the parameter mutation_num_genes exists or when mutation_type is None.

last_fitness = 0
def callback_generation(ga_instance):
    global last_fitness
    print("Generation = {generation}".format(generation=ga_instance.generations_completed))
    print("Fitness    = {fitness}".format(fitness=ga_instance.best_solution()[1]))
    print("Change     = {change}".format(change=ga_instance.best_solution()[1] - last_fitness))

# Creating an instance of the GA class inside the ga module. Some parameters are initialized within the constructor.
ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=num_generations,
                       num_parents_mating=num_parents_mating, 
                       fitness_func=fitness_function,
                       sol_per_pop=sol_per_pop, 
                       num_genes=num_genes,
                       init_range_low=init_range_low,
                       init_range_high=init_range_high,
                       parent_selection_type=parent_selection_type,
                       keep_parents=keep_parents,
                       crossover_type=crossover_type,
                       mutation_type=mutation_type,
                       mutation_percent_genes=mutation_percent_genes,
                       callback_generation=callback_generation)

# Running the GA to optimize the parameters of the function.
ga_instance.run()

# After the generations complete, some plots are showed that summarize the how the outputs/fitenss values evolve over generations.
ga_instance.plot_result()

# Returning the details of the best solution.
solution, solution_fitness, solution_idx = ga_instance.best_solution()
print("Parameters of the best solution : {solution}".format(solution=solution))
print("Fitness value of the best solution = {solution_fitness}".format(solution_fitness=solution_fitness))
print("Index of the best solution : {solution_idx}".format(solution_idx=solution_idx))

prediction = numpy.sum(numpy.array(function_inputs)*solution)
print("Predicted output based on the best solution : {prediction}".format(prediction=prediction))

if ga_instance.best_solution_generation != -1:
    print("Best fitness value reached after {best_solution_generation} generations.".format(best_solution_generation=ga_instance.best_solution_generation))

# Saving the GA instance.
filename = 'genetic' # The filename to which the instance is saved. The name is without extension.
ga_instance.save(filename=filename)

# Loading the saved GA instance.
loaded_ga_instance = pygad.load(filename=filename)
loaded_ga_instance.plot_result()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a package that does not need assembly and can be used for any problem:

https://pypi.org/project/geneticalgorithm/

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is basically a plug but I think you guys will like it!

[image: EasyGA logo]

EasyGA is a python package designed to provide an easy-to-use Genetic Algorithm. The package is designed to work right out of the box, while also allowing you to customize features as you see fit.

Here is the wiki, it does the best at explaining how the flow works.
https://github.com/danielwilczak101/EasyGA/wiki

**This is all you need to get it working:**

```
pip3 install EasyGA
```

**and some sample code:**

```
import EasyGA

# Create the Genetic algorithm
ga = EasyGA.GA()

# Evolve the genetic algorithm
ga.evolve()

# Print your default genetic algorithm
ga.print_generation()
ga.print_population()
```

Answer (score 0):

scikit-opt

https://github.com/guofei9987/scikit-opt

```
import numpy as np


def schaffer(p):
    '''
    This function has plenty of local minimum, with strong shocks
    global minimum at (0,0) with value 0
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization
    '''
    x1, x2 = p
    part1 = np.square(x1) - np.square(x2)
    part2 = np.square(x1) + np.square(x2)
    return 0.5 + (np.square(np.sin(part1)) - 0.5) / np.square(1 + 0.001 * part2)
```

Step2: do Genetic Algorithm

```
from sko.GA import GA

ga = GA(func=schaffer, n_dim=2, size_pop=50, max_iter=800, prob_mut=0.001, lb=[-1, -1], ub=[1, 1], precision=1e-7)
best_x, best_y = ga.run()
print('best_x:', best_x, '\n', 'best_y:', best_y)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAucy.png)